# Which integers have exactly 3 distinct positive factors?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, contest-math

> Which integers have exactly 3 distinct positive factors? For example, 4 and 9 do but 5 and 6 don't.

I think the answer should be all odd square numbers, that are not also perfect cubes but I'm not sure.

Comment: does 2*3*5  =30 fit this ?

Comment: Any integer $n$ has $1$ and $n$ as factors. That's $2$ factors in the bag already. But any integer can be factored into a product of primes...

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee I think $30$ has more factors than that. What about $15$ and $1$?

Comment: Squared primes. $p^2$.

Comment: I think you are close, but the odd square number $225$ has more than $3$ distinct positive factors.

Comment: If they exactly three distinct prone factors, they can't be  square.

Comment: $81$ is an odd square number but its got plenty more than $3$ positive divisors. You've got the prime-numbers tag in your question, so maybe that's a hint

Comment: Do $1$ and the number itself count as "factors" ? "Divisors" would be clearer. "Prime factor" would be something different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we consider $1$ to be a "factor", then exactly the integers $-p^2$ and $p^2$ , where $p$ is a prime number, have exactly $3$ positive factors , namely $1$ , $p$ and $p^2$

If $1$ does not count (but the number itself, if it is positive), then the answer would be the numbers $-p^3$ and $p^3$ where $p$ is a prime number , having $p$ , $p^2$ and $p^3$ as the positive factors.

As mentioned by Jyrki, in the case that $1$ does not count we can also choose $\pm pq$ for any pair of two distinct primes $p$ and $q$. Then, the positive factors are $p$ , $q$ and $pq$

Comment: If $1$ doesn't count then $pq$, with $p$ and $q$ distinct primes also works.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, I overlooked this possibility.

Comment: aka any distinct semiprime or a cube.

Comment: in both cases it would make sense to present a proof and not only claim something

Comment: @miracle173 For a proof, consider that the number $N=p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_n^{a_n}$ has $(a_1+1)\cdots (a_n+1)$ divisors. When can this be $3$ respective $4$ ?

Comment: i thought that you should improve your answer and not explain it to me. I already know this.

Comment: I often prove my claims, but this time I see no reason. I think it is not difficult to find out why there are no more numbers.